# Order of operations in for loops in C

Tags: c, for-loop

In the following floor loop, how would `sum += n --` be evaluated? I'm very, very confused...

```
int sum;
for(sum=0;n>0;sum+=n--);
```

Comment: @both above comments : in C there are many constructs that cannot be found out by experiment, because they are undefined. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-undefined-behavior.

Comment: Yet again, stop. writing. rubbish. code.  If it's confusing, why did you write it like that?  Why did you not just split it up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For `sum += n--` the following operations are performed

- add `n` to `sum`
- decrement `n`

With `sum += --n`

- `n` is decremented
- the new value of `n` is added to `sum`

`n--` is called *postdecrement*, and `--n` is called *predecrement*

Answer (score 3):

That has to do with *post-* and *predecrement* operations. Predecrement operations first decrease the value and then are used in other operations while postdecrement ones first get used in operations (addition in the case) and decrement the value only after this.

All in all, the order will be as follows:

- `sum` is incremented by `n`
- `n` is decremented

Answer (score 0):

A very simple example I would like to demostrate.
Let us consider two variables `a=1` and `b=4`
the statement `a=b` will assign the value of b to a,

In the statement `a=b++` , first the value of `b` is assigned to `a` and then the value of `b` is incremented.

If the value of `a`was 1 and value of `b` was 4, then after using `a=b++`, the value of `a` will become 4 and the value of `b` will become 5.

The statement `a=b++`can be visualised as

`a=b;`

then

`b=b+1;`

Similarly, in your case, you have `sum+=n--` which can be broken down as

`sum=sum+(n--)`

or

`sum=sum+n`

then

`n=n-1`

Here again, first the value of `sum+n` will be assigned to `sum`, then the value of `n` will be decremented by 1